# Rails :uniqueness validation not finding previous records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I'm having a bizzarre glitch, where Rails does not validate the uniqueness of an attribute on a model, despite the attribute being saved perfectly, and despite the validation being written correctly.

I added a validation to ensure the uniqueness of a value on one of my Rails models, `Spark`, with this code:

```
validates :content_hash, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

The `content_hash` is an attribute created from the model's other attributes in a method called using a `before_validation` callback. Using the Rails console, I've confirmed that this hash is actually being created before the validation, so that is not the issue.

When I call in the Rails console `spark.valid?` on a spark for which I know a collision exists on its `content_hash`, the console tells me that it has run this query:

```
Spark Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "sparks" WHERE "sparks"."content_hash" = '443524b1c8e14d627a3fadfbdca50118c6dd7a7f' LIMIT 1
```

And the method returns that the object is valid. It seems that the validator is working perfectly fine, and is running the correct query to check the uniqueness of the `content_hash`, the problem is instead on the database end (I'm using sqlite3). I know this because I decided to check on the database myself to see if a collision really exists using this query:

```
SELECT "sparks".* FROM "sparks" WHERE "sparks"."content_hash" = '443524b1c8e14d627a3fadfbdca50118c6dd7a7f'
```

Bizarrely, this query returns  nothing from the database, despite the fact that I can see with my own eyes that other records with this `content_hash` exist on the table.

For some reason, this is an issue that exists exclusively with the `content_hash` attribute of the `sparks` table, because when I run similar queries for the other attributes of the table, the output is correct.

The `content_hash` column is no different from the others which work as expected, as seen in this relevant part of my `schema.rb` file:

```
create_table "sparks", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "spark_type"
    t.string   "content_type"
    t.text     "content"
    t.text     "content_hash"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
end
```

Any help on this problem would be much appreciated; I'm about ready to tear my hair out over this thing.

Comment: Is that a typo with the colon in front of the word `true` in `:uniqueness => :true`?

Comment: Yeah that was just a typo with the question, sorry. My code has it without the colon.

Comment: What does `select * from sparks where content_hash like '44%'` have to say?

Comment: That actually worked. Do you think the hashed value is too long to look up in the database?

Comment: But what is the output? I'm not convinced that you have a duplicate. Also, you should have a unique constraint inside the database if you care at all about having correct data.

Comment: It outputs the other sparks with the same content_hash. There are 3 now, so there is definitely a duplication. Yeah, I know that, but I also want to take action based on if there is a collision on the rails side, so it's most important that the validation works here.

Comment: If `SELECT "sparks".* FROM "sparks" WHERE "sparks"."content_hash" = '443524b1c8e14d627a3fadfbdca50118c6dd7a7f'` doesn't find anything then you don't have a duplicate. Unless maybe you have a corrupt SQLite database file.

Comment: That doesn't find anything, but if i keep the query exactly the same and change the "=" to a "like" then it finds the records just fine. I'm going to try dropping my database and recreating it from scratch to see if that does anything.

Comment: Try a `.schema` from the SQLite shell to make sure the columns are the type you think they are. SQLite's loose interpretation of SQL data types can be problematic.

Comment: Okay, I managed to fix the problem. For some reason when I changed the column type from "text" to "string" my database started working again. Totally freakin weird.

Comment: You should add that as an answer and then accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to fix the problem. I think it was an sqlite3 issue, because everything worked perfectly once I changed the type of `content_hash` from a `text` column to a `string` column. Weird.